# Laravel Backpack CRUD returns local.ERROR: Undefined index: columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I've just installed Backpack in my Laravel project. I followed the steps for creating general TourCrudController, but I get a 500 error and in logs the main issue is

> local.ERROR: Undefined index: columns

. I did not make any changes in CRUD files except the route (made it plural and changed it in crud routes file, view, and TourCrudController). Other CrudControllers work just fine. Could you help me find the issue, please?

```
class TourCrudController extends CrudController
{
public function setup()
    {
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Tour');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/tours');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('tour', 'tours');
    }
```

```
Route::group([
...
], function () { // custom admin routes
    Route::crud('tours', 'TourCrudController');
}); // this should be the absolute last line of this file
```

Comment: The problem seems to appear only on local machine in precompiled views. Clearing cache did not solve the problem on local machine, but the same clearing did not break the work on server. Any ideas why it may happen?

Answer (score 1):

I close the issue, the bug was fixed in 4.0.11 version. If somebody needs it

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2170